# Does Sage of Ages roll replacement happen before or after the roll?

Tags: dnd-4e

Sage of ages, level 24:

> Keeper's Prescience (24th level): At the start of each of your turns, roll a d20. You can use the result of that roll in place of any one d20 roll you make before the start of your next turn.

Does this replacement occur before the d20 roll or can it be used to replace an already rolled d20?

Comment: The power states "In place of the the roll" not "In place of the result". I don't have a reference but I'm leaning toward before.

Comment: I agree with dpatchery, and also... the feature is named Keeper's _Pre_ science. :)

Comment: I disagree. It says "You can use the result...in place of any one d20 roll you make...". The d20 roll must have actually taken place for the Prescience roll to replace it.

Comment: One of you folks who favor the before the roll interpretation should give an answer so that the rest can vote you up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The use of the d20 is decided before the result of the roll is known**

> You can use the result of that roll in place of any one d20 roll you make before the start of your next turn.

The key here is that you are replacing a roll, and not a result.

Compare Elven Accuracy [<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1450)

> Trigger: You make an attack roll and dislike the result.

where the trigger is a roll with a result, rather than just a roll.

and Divine Guidance[<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=5331)

> Trigger: An ally within 10 squares of you makes an attack roll against your oath of enmity target
>
> Effect: The target makes a second attack roll and uses either result

Comment: If the wording were _in place of any one d20 roll you **would** make_, then I would interpret it this way.

Comment: @okeefe, certainly adding the word ***would*** would make the KP way more clear. With respect to Divine Guidance would you allow the player to roll before Divine Guidance is used? Or do you see some difference that I am missing between them?

Comment: EA and DG are both quite explicit: "You rolled and want to roll another die" and "You get to roll twice".  KP's wording is more ambiguous.

Comment: @okeefe is DG that explicit? Were it not for EA I would assume that DG (and KP since it has the same wording) worked after the roll, as the "make/makes" is ambiguous in terms of timing, but the reading of after the roll is slightly more natural. It is only the very explicit nature of EA that makes me think that DG and KP are different from EA.

Answer (score 6):

There doesn't seem to be any errata for this, so interpret it as written.

> in place of *any one d20 roll you make* before the start of your next turn.

I interpret this to mean that you roll whatever d20s you normally roll, and can swap the Prescience roll after the fact.

Aside: There's some forum grumbling that this is overpowered.

Comment: This is how I have always interpreted it.